# Scale invariance and stress energy tensor

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, noethers-theorem, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, trace, scale-invariance

I have seen in a paper [1] that in a quantum field theory scale invariance takes place provided the stress energy tensor is traceless. How this is true?

References:

1. "INFINITE CONFORMAL SYMMETRY IN TWO-DIMENSIONAL QUANTUM FIELD THEORY" by A A Belavin, A M Polyakov and A B Zamolodchikov. Nuclear Physics B241(1984) 333-380.

Comment: Are you sure that the statement you read was not the converse? The stress energy tensor is traceless provided scale invariance takes place.

Comment: The details of the paper is "INFINITE CONFORMAL SYMMETRY IN TWO-DIMENSIONAL QUANTUM FIELD THEORY" by A A Belavin, A M Polyakov and A B Zamolodchikov. Nuclear Physics B241(1984) 333-380.

Comment: The statement is "In the quantum field theory the scale symmetry (1.1) takes place provided the stress energy tensor is traceless" where (1.1) is the scale transformation equation.

Comment: Maybe in 2D the propositions are equivalent. You could try to have a look at Di Francesco- Mathieu- Sénéchal's textbook on Conformal Field Theory...

Comment: I have got it. Thanks. The statement is correct for any dimension but the converse, i.e, "the scaling symmetry implies stress-energy tensor is traceless" is not true in general.

Comment: @ParthaPaul I suggest you use web-links rather than textual references. They are quicker to check out. After all the hypertext concept was invented/propelled by physicists at CERN.